# Calculate area NDSI in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, area, pixel

I am new to using GEE.
I am trying to calculate the area of NDSI values gte 0.
For this, I make a function where I already do the conditional.
So I have images with values 0 and 1. Then I added a band where only the values of 1 were.

When I try to calculate the area of this band for each day that I have in the list. The area was not calculated or I get errors (in the console window) where it tells me that the band selection is invalid.
or in the print of the area, it indicates the legend of "NULL".

I'm a bit confused, because I don't know exactly what I'm failing in my code.

This is my code:

```
//Agora vamos trabalhar com coleções de imagens e séries temporais

//Definimos nossa região de interesse
Map.centerObject(roi,8)

//Agora vamos abrir nossa primeira imagem
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
                .select('B.*')
                .filterBounds(roi) //Esta função vai filtrar as imagens que interceptam a área de estudo
                .filterDate('2021-12-31','2022-01-15') //Defindo o intervalo das imagens
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',10)) //aqui puxamos um filtro atrelado as propriedades da imagem
                .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11, 5, 'month'))
                .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')//ordenamos da imagem com menor percentual para a maior
                
//Quantas imagens temos na coleção?
print('Qtds img', collection.size())

//Precisamos aplicar o fator de escala em toda as img
//Para isso iremos usar o map()
//Definir uma função
//Podermos recortar as imagens de uma ver só para uma região

//Função                              
function scale_and_ndsi(image){
                      var ndsi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3','B11']) .rename('NDSI')
                      var snow = ndsi.eq (1) . rename ("SNOW")
                      //encerrar a função
                      //Para encerrar a função multiplicamos a imagem pelo fator de escala
                      //Adicionamos o NDVI e copiamos as propriedades da coleção para gerar análises temporais
                      return image.multiply(0.0001)
                                  .addBands(ndsi) //Adicionando a banda do NDVI
                                  .addBands (snow)
                                  .clip(roi) //recortando a região
                                  .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())//Copiando as propriedades 
                                  .set({data: image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')})//adicionando a propriedade por data
              
}

//Agora vamos aplicar os cálculos da função na nossa coleção de imagens
var collection_scale= collection.map(scale_and_ndsi)
print('Quais bandas temos?', collection_scale.first().bandNames())


//Como exportar todas as imagens?
//Vamos criar um loop (com o map)

//Primeiro vamos criar uma lista com a propriedade data
var dias = collection_scale.aggregate_array('data')
print('imprimir a lista de datas',dias)

//Vamos aplicar uma função que irá ser executada em cada data
var datas = dias.getInfo() //use o getInfo com moderação (importante!!!)
var serie_temporal = datas.map(loop);//função para uma lista

//Estrutura da função
function loop(data){
           
           //Aqui nos aplicamos um filtro de data em casa imagem
           var collection_scale= collection.map(scale_and_ndsi).filter(ee.Filter.eq('data',data))
           Map.addLayer(collection_scale.select('SNOW'), 
                                        {palette:['white','yellow','green'], min:0, max:1}, 
                                        'SNOW '.concat(data))

          //Exportando as multiplas imagens
          Export.image.toDrive({
                                  image: collection_scale.select('SNOW').first(),
                                  folder: 'SNOW23',
                                  description: 'NDSI_'.concat(data),
                                  region: roi,
                                  crs:'EPSG:4326',
                                  scale: 10,
                                  maxPixels: 1e13
                                  })   }

// mapping area function over the collection
function addArea(scale_and_ndsi) {
  var area_NDSI = ee.Image.pixelArea()
            .divide(1e6) // Area in Sq. KM
            .reduceRegion({
                reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
                geometry: roi,
                scale: 10,
                bestEffort: true
                });
  return scale_and_ndsi.set(area_NDSI);  
}

var area_collection = collection_scale.select('SNOW').map(addArea);
print(area_collection.get ("area"),area_collection);


//Vamos visualizar tudo em gráfico??
//Vamos criar algumas amostras (regiões parao observar a variação)
var SSPM = roi.first().geometry();
// rebuild a feature collection with custom labels
var amostras = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Feature(SSPM,{label : 'SSPM'}));

//print('quais amostras temos', amostras)

//Vamos gerar nosso gráfico
var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:collection_scale, 
  regions:amostras, 
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  band:'NDSI', 
  scale:20, 
  xProperty:'system:time_start', 
  seriesProperty:'label'
  
})
  .setChartType('ScatterChart') // 'ScatterChart', 'LineChart', and 'ColumnChart'
    .setOptions({
          title: 'NDSI das amostras ao longo dos anos',
          vAxis: {title: 'NDSI'},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 5,
          series: {
          0: {pointShape: 'circle',color: 'violet'},//considera o valor da ordem merge
                    }});

//print(chart)

//Adicionar o chart no mapa
//Add o Gráfico no Painel
chart.style().set({
  position:'bottom-left',
  width:'500px',
  height:'300px'
})

Map.add(chart)
```

Also, I share the link of my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/29b2926941f4acf589636e1225f78d4c

Comment: Please share the asset to test the code

Answer (score -1):

There is no data from sentinel everyday.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).